# OpenSSL can't decrypt file

Tags: openssl

I have a file supposedly encrypted with AES-128-CBC. [1enc.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P9fbgk60UFGEIR62EZ575mIHUIOFqQQh/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the key (password) to it `f52b687c5824fd41`.

I can decrypt it with [aes.online-domain-tools.com](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/)
[Here's what it looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKjkH.png)
Here I enter the desired settings (as in the picture), click "> Decrypt!" and download the file by clicking on "Download as a binary file".

Then I rename the downloaded file to "1dec.ts". It turns out here is such a decrypted file: [1dec.ts](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lldNDE-kZsQWOf_TmRxMJh8FUpiOAaLI/view?usp=drive_link)
This is a ts container file containing mp3 audio stream. It plays fine in the MPC-BE player.

But I can't decrypt the 1enc.ts file with OpenSSL.
Here are the commands I tried:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -in R:\Downloads\1enc.ts -out R:\Downloads\1dec.ts -pass pass:f52b687c5824fd41
bad magic number

openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -k f52b687c5824fd41 -in R:\Downloads\1enc.ts -out R:\Downloads\1dec.ts
bad magic number

openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -in R:\Downloads\1enc.ts -out R:\Downloads\1dec.ts -pass pass:f52b687c5824fd41
bad decrypt

openssl enc -d -aes-128-cbc -nosalt -k f52b687c5824fd41 -in R:\Downloads\1enc.ts -out R:\Downloads\1dec.ts
bad decrypt
```

What am I doing wrong?